# SQL - SELECT unique rows AND older than 4 hours

Tags: sql

I'm trying to SELECT all rows which are older than 4 hours, only unique ones, and limit them with 250 rows.

My database looks like this:

```
id | titleid | version | timestamp
1  | TEST1   | 1.00    | 2019-03-23 02:40:33
2  | TEST1   | 1.01    | 2019-03-23 02:40:33
3  | TEST1   | 1.02    | 2019-03-23 02:40:33
4  | TEST2   | 1.50    | 2019-03-23 02:40:33
5  | TEST2   | 1.51    | 2019-03-23 02:40:33
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM patch_queue m1
LEFT JOIN patch_queue m2 ON (m1.titleid = m2.titleid AND m1.id < m2.id)
WHERE timestamp <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR) AND m2.id IS NULL
LIMIT 250
```

Which should do the trick. I'm just not sure how I can combine it into one. It throws:

> Column 'timestamp' in where clause is ambiguous

Does anyone happen to know how can I do this?

Desired result:

```
id | titleid | version | timestamp // they're all older than 4 hours in this case
3  | TEST1   | 1.02    | 2019-03-23 02:40:33
5  | TEST2   | 1.51    | 2019-03-23 02:40:33
```

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: Which `timestamp` in the `WHERE` clause? If it's the one from `m1` then write `m1.timestamp`;  if it's the one from `m2` then write `m2.timestamp`.

Comment: How come you show sample data from one table and then have a query with two tables?  Desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify `m1.timestamp`:

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM patch_queue m1
LEFT JOIN patch_queue m2 ON (m1.titleid = m2.titleid AND m1.id < m2.id)
WHERE m1.timestamp <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR) AND m2.id IS NULL
LIMIT 250
```

Output:

```
id  titleid version timestamp
3   TEST1   1.02    2019-03-23 02:40:33
5   TEST2   1.51    2019-03-23 02:40:33
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6aGVZcXQuMRVCATtsQHY8G/0)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want one row per `titleid`, where the `titleid` has no records in the past 4 hours:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.timestamp = (select max(t2.timestamp)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.titleid = t.titleid
                    ) and
      t.timestamp < now() - interval 4 hour
order by timestamp desc
limit 250;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, Gordon. I've updated my question as I was missing some info. Sorry about that. Maybe it's more clear now.

Comment: @AppelFlap . . . Are you saying that this did not produce the desired results?